# Why can we choose a basis from the cycles in the nullspace of an incidence matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let $D = (V,A)$ connected graph, and let $M$ be the incidence matrix of $D$. I can clearly see that a circulation must be in the nullspace of $M$, because for every $v\in V$ the sum of the weights on "in" edges are equal to the sum of the weights on "out" edges. The dimension of the nullspace is $|A|-(|V|-1)$ (the rank of $M$ is $|V|-1$, because $D$ is connected). We choose a tree in $D$, there are exactly $|V|-1$ edges in there, and if we put back each edge one bye one, then every edge makes a unique cycle. I think those cycles are the basis of the nullspace, because there are exactly  $|A|-(|V|-1)$ of them, but I dont know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\ e_1,e_2,\dots, e_{|A|+1-|V|}\ $ are the edges of $\ D\ $ that are not in the tree, $\ C_i\ $ the unique cycle which edge $\ e_i\ $ forms with the edges of the tree, and $\ j\ne i\ $, then $\ e_j\ $ is not in $\ C_i\ $. Thus, if $\ K_i\ $ is the column vector corresponding to the cycle $\ C_i\ $, then $\ K_{ie_i}\ne0\ $ and $\ K_{ie_j}=0\ $ if $\ i\ne j\ $.  Can you then see why $\ K_1, K_2,\dots,K_{|A|+1-|V|}\ $ must be linearly independent?

Comment: What does $K_{ie_j}$ mean?

Comment: If $K_{ie_j}$ means the scalar product of $K_i$ and $e_j$, then if we assume that $K_i$ can be written of the linear combination of other $K_j$’s , then taking the scalar product with $e_i$ on both sides, we get a zero on one side, and nonzero on the other side, which is a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: The entries of $\ K_i\ $ are indexed by the edges of $D$ (just like the columns of $\ M\ $), so if $\ e\ $ is any edge of $\ D\ $, then $\ K_{ie}\ $ is the $\ e^\text{th}\ $ entry of $\ K_i\ $.  Apologies for not being clearer.  Although you've misinterpreted the meaning of this, you're on the right track.  If $\ \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{|A|+1-|V|}c_jK_j\ $ is a linear combination of the $\ K_j$s, then the $\ e_i^\text{th}\ $ entry of the linear combination is just $\ K_{ie_i}c_i\ $, so if the linear combination is zero, then $\ c_i\ $ must be zero for all $\ i\ $, because $\ K_{ie_i}\ne0\ $.

Comment: It’s clear now. Thank you!:)